# Seeking birth record for Margery/Margaret Eddison b. abt 1879 in Scotland?

Tags: birth-records, scotland, 1870s, 1880s

Margery (or possibly Margaret) Eddison is my 2nd great grandmother. Eddison is her maiden name. I have been unable to find her birth or any records for her. I know about her only because my dad told me about her after doing some internet research a few years ago.

Here is all the information I have about her husband, John Leiper.

- He was born 11 Aug 1881 in Portlethen, Kincardineshire, Scotland.
- His mother was called Ann Urquhart Leiper (I haven't found a maiden name).
- His father was also called John Leiper.
- According to my dad, he may have been a tool maker or something similar.

Here is all I know about my great grandmother, Mina Urquhart Leiper, which is the only child of John and Margery that I know about.

- She was born about 1909 in Scotland.
- In 1936, she married Robert James Jackson in Dumbarton, Scotland.
- She gave birth to my grandma in 1943 in Edmonton, Middlesex, England.
- According to my dad, she was possibly a teacher.

Comment: I've removed the name of your grandmother because she was born less than 100 years ago. Our privacy policy is in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry that I forgot about not putting the names of people who were born less than 100 years ago.

Comment: I think you should focus this question on finding a marriage record for John Leiper. There are so many more sources available now compared to even a few years ago so I don't think it would hurt to re-research who his wife may have been before assuming it was Margarey/t Eddison.

Comment: I will post a question about John's marriage record. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this should be considered a candidate birth record for "Margarey/t Eddison" indexed as Marjory Addison:

> ADDISON MARJORY F 1882 258/2 49 Cookney

I found it using these [Scotland's People search criteria](https://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk/record-results?search_type=people&dl_cat=statutory&dl_rec=statutory-births&surname=Addison&surname_so=exact&forename=Marjory&forename_so=starts&from_year=1870&to_year=1890&record_type=stat_births).

[Cookney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookney) is in Aberdeenshire which [adjoins Kincardineshire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kincardineshire).