# Looking for marriage record for John Leiper b. 1881 in Kincardineshire, Scotland

Tags: 19th-century, marriage-records, scotland

John Leiper is my 2nd great grandfather.  I would like to find his marriage record. I believe he married a lady called Margery or Margaret Eddison. My dad told me about her after doing some family research a few years ago. It is possible that it could be another woman though.

This link is a question I have asked about finding records for Margery/Margaret Eddison: [Any records for Margery/Margaret Eddison b. abt 1879 in Scotland](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13179/any-records-for-margery-margaret-eddison-b-abt-1879-in-scotland?noredirect=1#comment19151_13179)

Anyway, more about John Leiper:

- He was born on 11 Aug 1881 in Portlethen, Kincardineshire, Scotland.
- His mother was called Ann Urquhart Leiper (I haven't found a maiden name).
- His father was called John Leiper.
- He had a child called Mina Urquhart Leiper (my great grandmother) in 1909 in Scotland. You can found out more about her in the above link.
- I'm not sure if he had any other kids.
- Accoring to my dad, he could have been a toolmaker or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I performed a [search at Scotland's People](https://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk/record-results?search_type=people&dl_cat=statutory&dl_rec=statutory-marriages&surname=Leiper&surname_so=exact&forename=John&forename_so=starts&spsurname_so=exact&spforename_so=exact&from_year=1900&to_year=1910&record_type=stat_marriages) that returned 8 results.

The marriage that you favour is listed amongst them as:

> LEIPER JOHN ADDISON MARJORY 1905 168/1 748 748 St Nicholas

i.e. Margarey/t Eddison has been indexed as Marjory Addison.

Before assuming that this is the marriage of your ancestors I would recommend reviewing the other marriages to see if any of them are equally likely.